# List operation with [-1].Explain

Tags: list

[Can anybody explain what that avg rating line does & what is the use of apps_data[0][-1].... what does this [-1] do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RycEk.png)

Answer (score 0):

list[-1] returns the last element of the list e.g

```
array = [1,2,3]
print array[-1]  # outputs 3
```

Comment: apps_data is you 2 dimensional array, it means pick the last element of the first row i.e it returns 3.5 .